# How to retrieve references from group Checkbox name arrays using JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have a hard JS/jQuery riddle ! Hard because I couldn't find it on Google nor here, neither now, nor months ago when I was looking for it previously.

A large framework is using checkboxes in a table:

```
<table class="ListTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="blnChecked[70_20]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="some_unusable_gobbledy_gook" /></td>
    <td></td>...
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="blnChecked[71_20]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="some_more_unusable_gobbledy_gook" /></td>
    <td></td>...
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="blnChecked[70_25]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="some_further_unusable_gobbledy_gook" /></td>
    <td></td>...
  </tr>
</table>
```

I now need to collect all checkbox name *references* into an array: 70_20, 71_20 and 70_25 in the above example. Then join them up, and submit them as a URL parameter to a different page (although this joining is not essential to my question).

Question: **Using JS/jQuery on the same page, how do I get these references from the name strings in these (checked) checkboxes in an array ?**

I prefer not to use regexes (a bit messy, or 'overkill' for such a seeming trivial matter imho), although such a solution is not off my table.

(If someone asks why the table is structured as such: This is not my doing. But I can see that when such a form, in which this table is submitted to a PHP page, the PHP stores all such checkboxes into a single array, which is very nice, and I wanted to achieve a similar effect with JS/jQuery.)

Comment: Did you try doing a simple `<form method="POST" action="example.com"></form>`

Comment: Im not sure why you are suggesting this: I am asking to retrieve values using JS/jQuery, not how to submit it to the PHP file. Granted, it will retrieve the values, but it doesn't answer my question nor my problem of making GET requests (not POST).

Comment: I'm asking because your question is not clear. You said "How do I get these references in an array" but is that a javascript array or a PHP array? Additionally, given the HTML input, what should the output be?

Comment: Its a JS Array that I want. I have ammended the question a bit to make it clearer, and removed parts that were offroading the topic a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to create on client side the array is based on using:

- [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)
- string [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var retVal = $('table.ListTable :checkbox[name^="blnChecked["]:checked').map(function(idx, ele) {
        //
        // if the name value has always the same format...
        //
        return ele.name.replace('blnChecked[', '').replace(']', '');
        //
        // or....
        //
        // return ele.name.split('[').pop().replace(']', '');
        // return ele.name.substr(11, 5);
        //return ele.name.replace(/blnChecked\[(.*?)\]/g, '$1')
    }).get();
    var param = $.param({'param': retVal.join(',')});
    console.log('Array: ' + retVal);
    console.log('URL param: ' + param);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="ListTable">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="blnChecked[7125_2355]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="some_unusable_gobbledy_gook" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="blnChecked[71_20]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="some_more_unusable_gobbledy_gook" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="blnChecked[70_25]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="some_further_unusable_gobbledy_gook" /></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Very nice! This answers the question, but you are using some heavy tanks that I was hoping to steer away from

Comment: Yes, I can see that with substr. But then, you would have to use the substr twice (to get rid of the last ] ), making both possibilities equally muddy.

Comment: But what if name="blnChecked[7125_2355]" ? These references are not constant. Your previous answer was better.

Comment: @FlorianMertens My last proposal is a double replace: **ele.name.replace('blnChecked[', '').replace(']', '')** Let me know

Comment: For the record: I had hoped that there was a JS/jQuery gem that could parse the names automatically (like $("input[name=blnChecked]").name() or similar), like PHP does. This solution does answer the question, but Im a bit stumbled that its not as easy as apparent.